# Nextpeer in iOS game crashed in first line: NSNull length

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, nextpeer

Nextpeer in iOS crashed in first line of sdk initialization. SDK version: 1.4.9

Code:

```
[Nextpeer initializeWithProductKey:@"HERE USED GAME KEY FROM NEXTPEER"
                           andSettings:settings
                          andDelegates:[NPDelegatesContainer containerWithNextpeerDelegate:self]];
```

Crash log:

```
[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3760678
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3760678'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x362f012 0x28cce7e 0x36ba4bd 0x361ebbc 0x361e94e 0x23bdefc 0x23bde42 0x23be195 0x126708 0x126368 0x28e06b0 0x16a602 0x28e06b0 0x17b203 0x28e06b0 0x230c765 0x35b2f3f 0x35b296f 0x35d5734 0x35d4f44 0x35d4e1b 0x30a67e3 0x30a6668 0x1810ffc 0x17ad6 0x2fe5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

How can I resolve this problem? any framework missing to add?

Comment: If you're sure everything is setup according to their instructions you should ask Nextpeer support.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This happens only in simulator and works fine in real iPhone.

All is well now. But few days back nextpeer worked in simulator also but not now.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact their support team (support at nextpeer.com).
BTW, did you add the "other linker flags" (-ObjC, -all_load)?

From Nextpeer's documentation: 
In your project configuration, under Linking -> Other Linker Flags add the following flags for ALL CONFIGURATIONS:

-ObjC
-all_load